# Query with EntityFramework do not return any value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am new to entity framework and i try to make a simple query to get data from my database.
I have the next classes:

```
public class AppContext:DbContext
{
public DbSet<MyObject> mytable{get;set;}
}
```

```
public class MyObject
{
public int Id{get;set;}
public string name{get;set;}
}
```

And my controller is the next one:

```
public class HomeController:Controller{
private AppContext _context;

public HomeController(){
_context=new AppContext();
}

protected override void Dispose(bool disposing){
_context.Dispose();
}

public ActionResult Index(){
var objects=_context.mytable.ToList(); //here is the error
return View(objects);
}

}
```

Thanks in advance for help and sorry if this question sound dummy but I just started to learn Entity Framework.

I filled the table with some rows so there is information to query. I put some breakpoints in the controller but the var doesn't even appear in the console.

Comment: *the var doesn't even appear in the console* -- I don't quite understand what you mean there.

Comment: I mean that during the debug i want to see in the console what is store in the objects variable.

Comment: But do you mean that the breakpoint is never hit? Anyway, there's not much we can do with the code you show. Try to turn in into a [mre].

Comment: In my example, the objects variable should contain all a list<myobject> with all the entries from the database, right?

Comment: You need to call the api first